# What was the formulation of the Bracha about Yerushalayim in the times of the Temple?

Tags: history, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot, yerushalayim-jerusalem

In Shemona Esrei we pray that Hashem should return to Yerushalayim. Obviously while the Jews were in Yerushalayim during the time of the Bais Hamikdash this Bracha had to be different as it would not be sensible to pray that Yerushalyim should be built during the time of the first temple when it is in all its glory. In addition perhaps Shemona Esrei was first instituted after the end of the first Bais HaMikdash. Perhaps even during the times of the second Bais HaMikdash this Bracha was worded differently. Is there any source that describes the wording of this Bracha during the times of the Bais Hamikdash?

Comment: Are you asking about the first or second temple? I don't think there was a shmone esrei during the first temple and it definitely wasn't in all its glory in the second temple.

Comment: @GershonGold, is there anyone who places the content of Shemona Esrei in the first temple period?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_15022_328.pdf

Comment: Possibly relevant - http://www.hakirah.org/Vol14Zelcer.pdf

Comment: I've got a better one: the third Berachah of Birkath HaMazon is about rebuilding Yerushalayim, and we say the first three are DeOraitha -- What??

Comment: @SethJ It's not about rebuilding yerushalayim. It's about yerushalayim.

Comment: @double רחם  ?ובנה?

Comment: @SethJ Well that is our current request about yerushalayim. Moshe obviously didn't write that.

Comment: @double aa, why "obviously"? Because he didn't possess רוח הקודש?

Comment: @SethJ lol!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: http://www.rabbibrand.022.co.il/BRPortal/br/P102.jsp?arc=1907339

Answer (score 3):

The Tur in the laws of Biract Hamazon (OC 188) writes that they would pray that Jerusalem and the Temple should remain standing. The same can probably be said about Shmona esrei.

Comment: No time to look it up right now; does he say *why* they said that? Does he address the fact that we say the first three Berachoth are DeOraitha?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the bracha of רצה, apparently they used to say somethign similar to the Nussach we say on YomTov before Duchening; ותערב

This, according to an article in one of the recent קולמוס magazines (a monthly addition to the weekly משפחה magazine.)

Comment: ותערב is the standard Eretz Yisrael nusach post Churban. I don't know why you would expect them to say it pre-churban as well.

Comment: @double aa, a friend with a mild-moderate obsession with Nusah has told me that he's seen compelling evidence that, throughout Ashkenazi Nusah, certain patterns present themselves and provide hints at what was once Nusah Eretz Yisrael, including ותערב. I am not the expert, but are you strongly convinced that some form of it couldn't have existed pre-destruction?