# Date rebuilding Jerusalem appeared in birkas hamazon and me'en shalosh?

Tags: history, bentching

Do the references to rebuilding Jerusalem indicate when the birkas hamazon and me'en shalosh were first written, or were these references added at some point to existing brachot?

Do we know when the references to rebuilding Jerusalem were put in these two brachot?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31703/759

Comment: See also Berachos 48b